# 'HttpWebRequest' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Net'.

Tags: vb.net, ambiguous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Saved program and now it does not compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473990/saved-program-and-now-it-does-not-compile)

I have a whole bunch of these errors, along with designer errors and such. I checked the object browser and it's not ambiguous, only one instance of HttpWebResponse in system.net

I am at my wit's end. It compiled yesterday. I saved it and opened it today and it no longer compiles. There are a bunch of Designer errors too..

Comment: You might want to consider rebuilding the local copy of your project from your source control system to see if the problem clears.  Other than that, you really haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: Er what? I'm sorry, not following you.

Comment: Well, assuming you're actually using a source control system. Your description suggests that something has been corrupted in your project. Try a "Build/Clean Solution."

Comment: Nope. This is ridiculous. Designer won't open either. I'm considering painstakingly copying the project over to a new project.
Edit: Yeah, I'll do that. Might as well.

Comment: Ok, I'm just moving the whole project to a new solution. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try and clean your solution from within Visual Studio. Then rebuild. If this doesn't work, try to manually delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in your solution.